# Is it possible to output formated text in a text file?

Tags: c, winapi

I`m working at a little text editor. My application is a winapi one in C. The idea is to write text in a large textbox(like in notepad) and then when I press a button it will take all text into a buffer, format it after some rules and then put it in a .txt file.

For example, if my input is:

```
Anne \red(got) \blue(\bold(apples)) and \italic(\bold(snails!))
```

After I parse it, it`s possible to put it into a .txt file and after I open it to see it like this?

[image]

I want to thank everyone for their time. I got exactly what answer I wanted. Everyone here rocks

Comment: Use an existing format. Don't try to invent your own.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't want to reinvent Latex,Word,Notepad, I just want to exercise string parsing and this seemed like a very interesting way. I know in console it`s possible to do that

Comment: That depends on the program used to view the file. A normal editor (such as notepad) on a normal text file doesn't support colors or fancy formatting.

Comment: So you intend to write your own text editor though?

Comment: You should use [RTF](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10725) for the text file, and a [Win32 RichEdit control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787605.aspx) for the editor UI.  A RichEdit can load and create RTF. Use its publlc API to manipulate the text attributes as needed (fonts, sizes, colors, etc) and it will create the appropriate RTF for you.

Comment: For instance, Notepad uses a standard [Win32 Edit control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775458.aspx) and thus does not support formatting, but WordPad uses a RichEdit control and does support formatting.

Comment: If you are trying to learn, consider following [this tutorial](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/neatpad). It is very well-done and in-depth. It teaches you a lot of great things, with surprisingly good practices as far as online tutorials go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are programming for fun, just for the pleasure of it, and with the perspective of learning more. If that is the objective, then it is okay to invent your own formats and essay your own solutions.

The problem presented can be twofold:

1. does the format results need to be shown in the editor itself?
2. or do you just need to do something that is going to be rendered in an external program?

If you are after the first possibility, then you need some Win32 (given your environment) component that will show the formatting. That component is [RichEdit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/bb787877(v=vs.85).aspx), and it implements [RTF](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format), a codification that can be saved to a text file, and which is more or less standard.

If you have the second possibility in mind, then you can choose from a variety of codifications. You would just be creating a text editor, probably with some helpers that write part of the commands for the user. For example, you could be creating a HTML editor, or a RTF editor.

There is a third possibility, though. You create your own codification, and when saving, you translate that codification to HTML, and then open the document in a web browser.

Say that you have:

```
\bold(hello), world.
```

You would translate that to:

```
<html><body><b>hello</b>, world.</body></html>
```

The possibilities, as you can see, are inifinite.

Hope this helps.